# add statistical results in the grand summary row

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto, gt

I need to run a simple paired t-test on two columns of my table (see fig below), and I want it to be in the grand summary row (below the correlation).

[image]

Here's a minimal working example for you to play with:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
library(rstatix)

df <- structure(list(study = c("caius", "titium", "sempronius", "cicero", 
"titus"), control = c(452, 603, 243, 552, 173), treatment = c(482, 
383, 579, 360, 227), difference = c(30, -220, 336, -192, 54)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df %>% gt() %>%
  grand_summary_rows(
    columns = c(control, treatment, difference),
    fns = list(Mean ~ round(mean(.)),
               SD ~ round(sd(.))), 
    missing_text = " " 
  ) %>%
  grand_summary_rows(
    columns = c(difference),
    fns = list(Correlation ~ round(cor(control, treatment), 2)), 
    missing_text = " " 
  )
```

I guess that running the test within gt might be complicated, so I wanted to add the results as a string in the grand summary row, is there any way I could hard code that?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a minimal working code and a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput().

Comment: just did! sorry for the mishap @stefan!

Answer (score 1):

It depends which stats you want to show for your t-test, but as you table already contains the difference of the two variables you could e.g. add the p-value to the grand summary row like so:

```
df %>%
  gt() %>%
  grand_summary_rows(
    columns = c(control, treatment, difference),
    fns = list(
      Mean ~ round(mean(.)),
      SD ~ round(sd(.))
    ),
    missing_text = " "
  ) %>%
  grand_summary_rows(
    columns = c(difference),
    fns = list(
      Correlation ~ round(cor(control, treatment), 2),
      "p-value" ~ t.test(.x)[["p.value"]]
    ),
    missing_text = ""
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to report t-value, df, and p-value in a single row. but I guess I can just paste everything together. Thank you for the tip!